# Sort a nested list in python by inner list number

Tags: python, sorting

say I have a nested list such as this,

```
[
    ['a', [2, 3, 7]], 
    ['j', [63, 4, 0]], 
    ['c', [1, 155, 10]], 
    ['z', [0, 77, 7]], 
    ['f', [100, 42, 9]]
]
```

How do sort this by the chosen largest number in the innermost list? For instance, if we wanted to sort it by the first integer in each element's list from largest to smallest, the result would be

```
[
    ['f', [100, 42, 9]], 
    ['j', [63, 4, 0]], 
    ['a', [2, 3, 7]], 
    ['c', [1, 155, 10]], 
    ['z', [0, 77, 7]]
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a `key` that extracts the value by which to sort; here that is `element[1][0]`:

```
sorted(inputlist, key=lambda e: e[1][0], reverse=True)
```

The `reverse=True` is there to sort from largest to smallest.