# Sort by coordinates inside of a list, inside of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, coordinates

I have a program where I want to sort  by an x coordinate.

My list looks like this:

```
[('Name1', (449, 923, 634, 737)), ('Name2', (390, 1356, 613, 1133)), ('Name3', (1062, 1749, 1216, 1594))]
```

Each element of the original list has a name, and then a set of x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates. If I want to sort my list by the x2 coordinate, how would I do that?

I've searched around and found that you can use "itemgetter" to do something like this:

```
preds = sorted(preds, key=itemgetter(1))
```

But that is getting the whole set of coordinates. How would I sort by say, the third coordinate, specifically?

Comment: `sorted(preds, key=lambda x: x[1][2])`

Comment: Another dup: [Sort a nested list in python by inner list number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41736425/2823755)

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it was so simple, but for some reason I was stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can sort it with `key=lambda t:t[1][2]`

```
>>> preds = [('Name1', (449, 923, 634, 737)), ('Name2', (390, 1356, 613, 1133)), ('Name3', (1062, 1749, 1216, 1594))] 
>>> preds.sort(key=lambda t: t[1][2])
>>> preds
[('Name2', (390, 1356, 613, 1133)), ('Name1', (449, 923, 634, 737)), ('Name3', (1062, 1749, 1216, 1594))]
>>>
```